# Google cloud print doesn't work in Nexus 7 2th (Android 4.3)

Tags: android, android-4.3-jelly-bean, google-cloud-print

I got a problem with Google cloud print on Nexus 7 2th edition with Android 4.3. I using the [example code](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/android) in my app and it work fine on a lot of android devices except Nexus 7 and maybe some an others devices with android 4.3.

All work fine until I get this page.

[image]

I choose 'print to google drive' before. And then, if click on print button nothing happens... no any messages about starting new job or something else.

Maybe somebody can give some advices. Thanks a lot.

Comment: problem is clear) [webView.addJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) and @JavascriptInterface anotation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) we need to modify example code by add *@JavascriptInterface* annotation for all methods in *PrintDialogJavaScriptInterface* and change Properties>Android>Project Build Target to API 17+

```
final class PrintDialogJavaScriptInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public String getType() {
        return cloudPrintIntent.getType();
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public String getTitle() {
        return cloudPrintIntent.getExtras().getString(TITLE);
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public String getContent() {
        try {
            ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
            InputStream is = contentResolver.openInputStream(cloudPrintIntent.getData());
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int n = is.read(buffer);
            while (n >= 0) {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, n);
                n = is.read(buffer);
            }
            is.close();
            baos.flush();

            return Base64.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public String getEncoding() {
        return CONTENT_TRANSFER_ENCODING;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void onPostMessage(String message) {
        if (message.startsWith(CLOSE_POST_MESSAGE_NAME)) {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```